# Bash continue only if ping is down

Tags: linux, bash, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to create a script which will only continue when pinging is unresponsive.

I'm running into 2 main issues. One being that it will require 2 CTL-C commands to end the script, and the other issue being that the script will never end and will need killing.

Here are my attempts;

```
rc=0
until [ $rc -gt 0 ]
do
      ping 69.69.69.69 > /dev/null 2>&1
      rc=$?
done

## Here will be the rest of code to be executed
```

I feel this one above is very close as it requires the 2 CTL-C commands and continues.
Here is something I found on SO but can't get to work at all.

```
counter=0
while [ true ]
do
  ping -c 1 69.69.69.69 > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -ne 0 ] then
        let "counter +=1"
    else
        let "counter = 0"
    fi
    if [ $counter -eq 10 ] then
        echo "Here should be executed once pinging is down"
    fi
done
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: What specifically happens when you run the second version? Do you get error messages? What do they say?

Comment: Have a look at the suggestions I've made to your script and see if you like the condensed form (which sends a single ping ant waits 10 seconds for a response).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
while ping -c 1 -W 20 "$host" >& /dev/null
do
  echo "Host reachable"
  sleep 10  # do not ping too often
done
echo "Host unreachable within 20 seconds"
```

Comment: Thank you Alfe this achieved what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

There's a few issues with that:
Firstly the if statements are wrong
Use this format

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ] then;
```

or this other format

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
```

Secondly I suspect that your pings are not timing out

```
ping -c 1 -w 2 69.69.69.69 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

might be helpfull

Thirdly your loop will continue incrementing counter even after 10. You might want to quit after 10

```
while [ $counter -le 10 ]
```

If you would be happy with executing something if ping times out after x seconds without any response it could be all condensed (ten seconds in the example below):

```
ping -c 1 -w 10 69.69.69.69 >/dev/null 2>&1 || echo "run if ping timedout without any response"
```

Comment: Ah thank you for point the above out! You can tell I'm a novice. As Alfe's solution worked for me, I'm going to stick with that. You help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you think it's a good answer too mark it as a useful answer ... it will help with my reputation too ;)
We were all once novice :D